# why the list content is updated but the flutter doesn't reflected that in to ui?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've made a list(_cost) in flutter and a card view that whenever each of them is clicked by the user a value related to the index of that card will be shown from the list(_cost) but the problem is every time I clicked on a card it shows the null despite the related value in the list is not null.

```
class ActivityPeopleCard extends StatefulWidget{

  Activity activity;
  ActivityPeopleCard({this.activity});


  @override
  _ActivityPeopleCardState createState() => _ActivityPeopleCardState();
}

class _ActivityPeopleCardState extends State<ActivityPeopleCard> {

   List<double> _cost;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _cost = new List(widget.activity.peopleInvolved.length);

    return Container(
      child:new GridView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.activity.peopleInvolved.length,
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3), 

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new GestureDetector(
            onTap: ()=> setState(() => {_priceSet(index)}),
            child: _buildWidget(index)
            );
          },
        ),         
      );
   }
_buildWidget(int index){
  return new Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
    elevation: 5.0,
    child: Stack(children:<Widget>[               
      new Container(
        height: height/4,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width:height/15,
              height: height/15,         
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height/20),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width:2),       
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height/15),
              child: Image.asset(widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].imagePath, fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                Center(child: Text(widget.activity.peopleInvolved[index].name))
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ])
   );
 }

_priceSet(int index){
  setState(() {
    _cost[1]=5500;
  });
```

even I set _cost[1] to 5500 in _priceSet function but it shows null instead

Comment: i think that problem is you initialising the same _cost variable again. whenever setState method called it will re-render whole build method and  _cost value again initialised with old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call setState in `_priceSet`, it is re-running the build method in your `_ActivityCardPeopleState`, which is in turn re-initializing your _cost list with no values present (despite you setting one in your `_priceSet` method.)

Consider initializing the _cost variable in your stateful (`ActivityPeopleCard`)widget, and then pass it over to the state (`_ActivityPeopleCardState`)